# Extra characters sometimes getting tacked on to the end of a character array containing characters that have been extracted from a file

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I'm having trouble reading in shader files for OpenGL. Sometimes the files are read correctly and the shaders can be correctly initialized. Other times, they are not read correctly.

The way I read these files (containing the code for the shaders) is simple. I extract each character from the file into an array. That array then effectively becomes the code for the shader and can be passed to opengl for use.

The problem is, sometimes some extra characters are tacked onto the end of the array when I read shader file

So instead of this:

```
#version 410 core

in vec4 fragmentColor;
out vec4 color;

void main(){
    color = fragmentColor;
}
```

I get this:

```
#version 410 core

in vec4 fragmentColor;
out vec4 color;

void main(){
    color = fragmentColor;
}\377
```

And I end up with a black screen.

Again, this doesn't happen all the time, happening seemingly at random.

This is my function that actually reads the shader files and extracts the characters into an array. *(Heavy with comments since I'm assuming posting long code on here is a sin. But the function itself really isn't all that complicated)*

```
    const GLchar ** ReadShaders(std::string vertex, std::string fragment){


    char tempVert[10000];
    char tempFrag[10000];

    //Open shader files
    std::ifstream vert(vertex);
    std::ifstream frag(fragment);

    //Don't skip white lines
    vert >> std::noskipws;
    frag >> std::noskipws;

    //Read in vertex shader file by extracting each character into "tempVert"
    int vCount = 0;

    while( !vert.eof() ){

        vert >> tempVert[vCount];

        //Break if there are no more characters to read (I know this is redundant, will fix later)
        if(vert.eof()){
            break;
        }
        else{
            vCount++;
        }

    }

    //Debug
    std::cout << vCount << std::endl;

    //Create new char array the size of the number of characters extracted from shader file
    char * tempVertexSource = new (std::nothrow) GLchar[vCount];

    //Copy extracted characters into new "tempVertexSource" array
    for(int i = 0; i < vCount; i++){

        tempVertexSource[i] = tempVert[i];

    }

    //Debug
    std::cout << tempVertexSource << std::endl;

    //Read in fragment shader file by extracting each character into "tempFrag"
    int fCount = 0;

    while( !frag.eof() ){

        frag >> tempFrag[fCount];

        //Break if there are no more characters to read (I know this is redundant, will fix later)
        if(frag.eof()){
            break;
        }
        else{
            fCount++;
        }
    }

    //Debug
    std::cout << fCount << std::endl;

    //Create new char array the size of the number of characters extracted from shader file
    GLchar * tempFragmentSource = new (std::nothrow) GLchar[fCount];

    //Copy extracted characters into new "tempFragmentSource" array
    for(int i = 0; i < fCount; i++){
        tempFragmentSource[i] = tempFrag[i];
    }

    //Debug
    std::cout << tempFragmentSource << std::endl;

    //Create an array to hold both shader arrays (for return)
    const GLchar ** returnShaders = new (std::nothrow) const GLchar*[2];

    //Assign shaders
    returnShaders[0] = tempVertexSource;
    returnShaders[1] = tempFragmentSource;

    //Close files
    vert.close();
    frag.close();

    //Return
    return returnShaders;


}
```

Now, in my function, the number of characters that are extracted from a file is counted. So, this next part is where I'm confused (other then the fact that sometimes the error happens, and sometimes it doesn't).

When outputting (checking) the number of characters that have been extracted from a file I'll get this for a correct run:

```
Number of characters: 100

#version 410 core

in vec4 fragmentColor;
out vec4 color;

void main(){
    color = fragmentColor;
}
```

However, I'll get the same number of characters when an incorrect reading of the file happens as well:

```
Number of characters: 100

#version 410 core

in vec4 fragmentColor;
out vec4 color;

void main(){
    color = fragmentColor;
}\377
```

This doesn't make sense, since:

1) The random extra characters seemingly come out of nowhere and at random

2) The number of characters that have been extracted from the file are used for the size of the new array that will contain those characters, so this shouldn't even be possibly without those extra characters all being a part of the last character in the array.

So, for example: Going off of what I know, for this particular shader file that contains 100 characters, if I hardcode 99 for the size of the char array and the number of characters it will copy into this new array, sure I don't get any of the random characters at the end at times, but it also deletes the "}" character.

Making it:

```
#version 410 core

in vec4 fragmentColor;
out vec4 color;

void main(){
    color = fragmentColor;
```

I'm very confused, Thanks for any help

Comment: "happening seemingly at random" Strong hint for undefined behavior. "sometimes some extra characters are tacked onto the end" Strong hint for lack of the trailing null byte of a C-string.

Comment: @cad damn, I was going to quickly write "you are not appending a null terminator byte at the end of your string" as an answer, and then I was going to actually look at his code.

Comment: @cad Yep, I knew it would be something simple like that, that would make me look incredibly stupid haha. Adding a null terminator to the end of the allocated arrays did the trick. As in: tempVertexSource[vCount] = '\0'; . Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Mike Nakis, Same thing to you that I just told cad. And thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

After the `while` loop, explicitly add a zero terminator:

```
tempVert[++vCount] = 0;
```

It would be way better to (1) get the file size first, (2) allocate memory for it, plus 1 for the zero terminator, then (3) read the entire file into memory at once. As it is, you need to make sure your files are smaller than the static buffers you allocate here.

Comment: Haha, yep same thing everyone else said. I knew I was just being stupid somewhere. This set me on the right path, but not quite right. What I actually needed to do was set the null terminator after the newly allocated arrays I made. So: tempVertexSource[vCount] = '\0'; and tempFragmentSource[fCount] = '\0'; . This went in after I had copied the extracted values into the allocated arrays. Thanks again, I appreciate the quick help.